# How to override Entity Framework fluent mappings?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to create a new and dedicated Entity Framework DbContext for Integration Testing with in-memory SQLite database.Below is the OnModelCreating method:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(XXX).Assembly);
        var sqliteConnectionInitializer = new SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists<YYY>(modelBuilder);
        Database.SetInitializer(sqliteConnectionInitializer);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

As you can see I'm adding my usual fluent mappings - the same that I'm using for my "usual" context. The problem is that SQLite is a little different than SQLServer, so the mapping doesn't work i.e. I can't map this:

```
Property(x => x.Timestamp).HasColumnOrder(11).IsRequired().IsRowVersion().HasColumnName("timestamp");
```

Timestamps are not supported in SQLite. The question is: how can I override the fluent mapping i.e. by convention - in this case it's enough to get rid of the `IsRowVersion()` - it's totally OK not to have optimistic concurrency in integration tests.

Comment: Is the DbContext for integration testing derived from your "usual" one?

Comment: No it is not. It is a totally separate thing. I just got around the IsRowVersion() problem by removing it from the fluent mapping and in regular context mapping this by convention. However there are other problems waiting in line - i.e. some columns are mapped to "ntext" type which is not supported by SQLite.

Comment: I haven't tried this, so not confident to make an answer, but can you just use the modelBuilder to change the mappings after you add from assembly? `modelBuilder.Entity<ZZZ>().Property(x => x.Timestamp)...`

Comment: @ChrisCurtis This is working great so far! Do you know if there is any way I can iterate through those mappings, inspect the column type and alter if necessary? Currently it's killing me to go through 40 columns and prepare an override statement for each `xml` to `nvarchar`.

Comment: No, I don't know how to iterate through them. Ctrl+D in visual studio can be handy :)

Comment: I did browse through all the properties, but it seems that all the conventions are applied before fluent mappings. The only way to override fluent mapping is what you suggested. I was dealing with this for the whole day today trying different possibilities and ended up with 120 lines of overrides which is a real pain in the neck.